# Upload Files Using SCP/SFTP or more secure way in Android

Tags: android, ftp, sftp, scp

How to Upload Files Using SCP protocol in Android.

I don't have any idea. Please give me sample code or clear guidance.

I made following code using FTP. Its working fine. but Client said that FTP is a less secure protocol. They told me that use SCP instead of FTP. Any way these are the codes. Please let me know how can I do this in secure way(SCP or any relevant method please explain).

```
private String sendImageToServer(final String folderName, final File image) {
class FtpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try{

            FTPClient connection = new FTPClient();
            connection.connect("192.244.110.86");
            boolean imageUploaded = false;

            if (connection.login("root","1pass6")) {

                connection.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                connection.enterLocalPassiveMode();

                byte[] imageInBytes = new byte[(int) image.length()];
                try {

                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                            image);
                    fileInputStream.read(imageInBytes);

                    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                            imageInBytes);

                    boolean folderCreted = connection.makeDirectory(folderName);

                    if (folderCreted) {
                        System.out.println("folder created ");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("folder not created ");

                    }

                    imageUploaded = connection.storeFile(folderName+"/"+image.getName()+".jpg", in);

                    System.out.println("Image sent "+imageUploaded);
                    in.close();
                    connection.logout();
                    connection.disconnect();
                    if (imageUploaded) {
                        System.out.println("imageUploaded success");
                        return "success";
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("imageUploaded fail");
                        return "fail";
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    result = "fail";

                }

            } else {
                System.out.println("UNABLE TO LOG IN TO THE FTP");
            }


        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "fail";
        }
        return "fail";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        System.out.println("onPostExecute "+result);
        if (result.equals(UPLOAD_SUCCESS)) {
            image.delete();

            System.out.println("UPLOAD_SUCCESS");
        } else if (result.equals(UPLOAD_FAIL)) {
            System.out.println("UPLOAD_FAIL");                  

        }
    }

}

FtpAsyncTask ftpAsyncTask = new FtpAsyncTask();
ftpAsyncTask.execute();
return result;
}
```

Comment: Is this resolved? If yes, can you please post your code?

Comment: do you have ftp4j jar file with you. If yes, could you please provide me? I couldn't get this through net.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched in Google. Please try the below code. Now, I don't have server available with me to test.

```
                Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            // FTP URL (Starts with ftp://, sftp://, ftps:// or scp:// followed by hostname and port).
            Uri ftpUri = Uri.parse("scp://yourserver.com");
            intent.setDataAndType(ftpUri, "vnd.android.cursor.dir/lysesoft.andftp.uri");
            // Upload
            intent.putExtra("command_type", "upload");
            // FTP credentials (optional)
            intent.putExtra("ftp_username", "yoursshlogin");
            intent.putExtra("ftp_password", "yoursshpassword");
            //intent.putExtra("ftp_keyfile", "/sdcard/rsakey.txt");
            //intent.putExtra("ftp_keypass", "optionalkeypassword");
            // FTP settings (optional)
            //intent.putExtra("ftp_encoding", "UTF-8");
            // Activity title
            intent.putExtra("progress_title", "Uploading files ...");
            intent.putExtra("local_file1", "/sdcard/subfolder1/file1.zip");
            // Optional initial remote folder (it must exist before upload)
            intent.putExtra("remote_folder", "/home/youruser/");
            startActivityForResult(intent, UPLOAD_FILES_REQUEST);
```

Reference - http://www.lysesoft.com/products/andftp/AndFTPClient1.0.zip

If possible, can you test this and let me know whether it's working or not?